# Onestep Checkout problem

Tags: onepage-checkout, ce-1.8.1.0

My one page checkout isn't working. Whenever the *Place Order* button is displayed the page just reloads.

- There is een DOM element `checkout-payment-method-load`
- `Review` is present at the bottom op `info.phtml`
- There is a hardcoded button instead of `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('button') ?>` in `info.phtml`
- I've replaced the template & lay-out files with the base files

Comment: did ur extension is enabled?

Comment: @hariharan yes,  it is enabled

Comment: You should open the console and check what happens there when place order button is clicked.